# Xamarin forms Flex Layout Center Items

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a Flex Layout located in a StackLayout in my contextmenu.
In the Screenshot all below the black line(the white area) is the Flex Layout control.

The 9 Frames inside there are my Items which have a fixed size, but the ammount of them is variable.
As its obvious to see the Rows itself aren't centered inside the control, but exactly this is what I want to achieve.

I tried a lot with the Properties, but could not get the Items centered.
(Also a test with a 3 Column Grid to shrink the width of the Flex layout didn't work)

Someone here has some ideas what else I could try to achieve the desired result?

[image: Current State]

Comment: Can you post the XAML you're currently using to construct the FlexLayout?

Comment: since i was under some Time Preassure i had to work around(using a Grid and give it some layout logic). I didnt construct it via Xaml, due too some legacy stuff in our context menu it was created in c#. (Pretty straight forward: Constructor and Porperties set, then placed inside a StackLayout).

Answer (score 4):

`JustifyContent="SpaceAround"` will do the trick

For more Flex Layout options and element placing, have a look at [this site](http://flexbox.malven.co/?utm_campaign=Weekly%2BXamarin&utm_medium=web&utm_source=Weekly_Xamarin_171). They explain it with CSS, but the same properties are used in Xamarins FlexLayout too.

Comment: As mentioned in my initial Post, i already knew about the MSDN and tested all layout specific Properties as mentioned in the official documents. Since there was no working solution i consideres StackOverflow to see if there is maybe some minor detail i didnt see or issnt documented. But thank you anyway for your help.